# CMake cannot find OneAPI libraries mkl_gf_lp64 and mkl_gnu_thread

Tags: cmake, intel-mkl, oneapi

I am trying to adapt a source code originally written for Intel MKL to the latest OneAPI and compile it under **MacOS**.

I have modified the CMakeLists to find OneAPI libraries like this:

```perl
    option (USE_ONEAPI "Enable MKL solver support via OneAPI Base Toolkit" ON)
    ...
    if (USE_ONEAPI)
    message(STATUS "Seeking OneAPI libraries...")
    list(APPEND MKL_LIBS "mkl_core" "mkl_gf_lp64" "mkl_gnu_thread" "pthread")
    foreach (f ${MKL_LIBS})
        if (INTEL_ONEAPI_DIR)
            # user provided OneAPI directory
            set(oneapiMklDir "${INTEL_ONEAPI_DIR}/mkl/latest")
            message(STATUS "    Seeking for ${f} in custom path: ${oneapiMklDir}...")
            find_library (${f}_LIB ${f} PATH "${INTEL_ONEAPI_DIR}/mkl/lib/intel64/" DOC "MKLPARDISO (library)")
            include_directories ("${INTEL_ONEAPI_DIR}/mkl/include")
        else ()
            set(oneapiDir "/opt/intel/oneapi")
            set(oneapiMklDir "${oneapiDir}/mkl/latest")
            message(STATUS "    Seeking for ${f} in default path: ${oneapiMklDir}...")
            find_library (${f}_LIB ${f} HINTS "${oneapiMklDir}/lib" DOC "MKLPARDISO (library)")
            include_directories ("${oneapiMklDir}/include")
        endif ()
        if (${${f}_LIB} STREQUAL "${f}_LIB-NOTFOUND")
            message (FATAL_ERROR "OneAPI ${f} library not found")
        else()
            message (STATUS "OK: ${f} library successfully found")
        endif ()
        list (APPEND EXT_LIBS ${${f}_LIB})
    endforeach ()
    list (APPEND MODULE_LIST "MKLPARDISO")
    endif ()
```

And this is the outcome:

```
-- Seeking OneAPI libraries...
--     Seeking for mkl_core in default path: /opt/intel/oneapi/mkl/latest...
-- OK: mkl_core_LIB library successfully found
--     Seeking for mkl_gf_lp64 in default path: /opt/intel/oneapi/mkl/latest...
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:379 (message):
OneAPI mkl_gf_lp64 library not found
```

I am not sure why CMake fails to find those libraries. Are they not installed with OneAPI base and HPC toolkits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is old so likely you already found a solution, but since I'm going through oneapi questions I figured I'd answer for the next person.

The mkl_gf_lp64 is not included but mkl_intel_lp64 is.  The two are not equivalent so you would likely need mkl_intel_thread.

You can also use the oneAPI MKL Library Link Line Advisor to figure out exactly what you need.

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/oneapi/onemkl-link-line-advisor.html